# Как сделать фон у svg элемента фиксированным, чтобы при скролле изображение оставалось на месте?

Tags: html, css, svg

есть
[image: svg с фоном]

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                    <pattern id="image" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
                      <image x="0" y="0"  xlink:href="1111111.jpg" class="img" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
                    </pattern>
                </defs>
                <path fill="url(#image)" d="M47.5,-62.4C62.5,-54.5,76.1,-41.9,83.4,-25.6C90.7,-9.4,91.6,10.3,80.5,20.6C69.5,30.9,46.6,31.8,31.2,40.5C15.8,49.2,7.9,65.7,1.1,64.2C-5.8,62.7,-11.5,43.2,-26.9,34.5C-42.2,25.8,-67.2,27.9,-77.6,19.6C-88,11.3,-83.8,-7.3,-74.7,-20.9C-65.6,-34.4,-51.5,-43,-38.2,-51.4C-24.9,-59.8,-12.5,-68.1,1.9,-70.7C16.3,-73.3,32.6,-70.3,47.5,-62.4Z" transform="translate(100 100)" />
              </svg>
```

пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

только здесь у текста прописано style:

```
    background: url(gif.gif);
    background-size: 100%;

    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
```

как можно сделать такой же эффект, но только с фоном svg элемента?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста: 1.нужно, чтобы фон двигался, и через svg контур был виден изменяющийся фон? 2. Двигается svg контур и сквозь него видны разные участки заднего фона?

Comment: двигается svg контур и сквозь него видны разные участки заднего фона

Comment: на примере 2 одинаковых фона, один z-index 0, сверху слой z-index 2 и в нем текст со стилем "background: url(gif.gif);
    background-size: 100%;

    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;", к svg фону в самом html можно что-то похожее написать?

Comment: контур нефиксированный* как на примере текста, вместе с верхним слоем идет наверх

Comment: От gif голова разболелась, пожалуйста, не делайте так! По вопросу — вам нужен [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath), смотрите там анимацию. Там анимирован фон, обрезаемый фигурой, но ничего не мешает анимировать саму фигуру, получится эффект как [в старой доброй игре](https://youtu.be/DwZAnc3o6xg?t=3). Если не разберётесь, пишите, пока не знаю как оформить в ответ, т.к. не понимаю какой вам фон нужен и какая обрезка.

Comment: необходимо реализовать домашнюю страницу как на сайте https://www.humaan.com/